# How can I add progressDialog or spinner to already finished app?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have to update some application. It is already in use, so I don't want to make big changes...

I want to add a progress dialog or a spinner every time when new activity is loaded. I read some articles and questions here like I have to use AsyncTask and so on. But I want to know if there is any easier way. Maybe something like creating some function which will showing spinner/progressDailog until new layout is loaded.

If you know what I want, can you tell me, if it is possible? Thanks

EDIT: I have one idea. Could I create layout with spinner, which would overlay the current layout? If yes, how?

EDIT two: AsyncTask

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

   //  Some code here

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CustomAsyncTaskResult<User> result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        ((LoginActivity)mContext).getResult(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is - no, there is no simple way.  If you want to display a spinner while an activity is loading, you need to create an asynctask (or any other separate thread).  The good news is that you can create one asynctask and reuse it in all of your activities.  The bad new is that you don't have any choice but to modify every one of your activities where you want to add the spinner.

Comment: Ok, I used asynctask, the progress dialog was displayed, then dissapeared, but the new layout was display after cca 5sec. What should I do? The code is shown in the question.

Comment: @user3808179 The reason for this is that you have to do the initialisation in the `doInBackground` method.  As it stands now, your asynctask doesn't really do anything asynchronously.  You can't get away without some serious refactoring - you have to change the way you initialise activities, namely do most of the initialisation in the asynctask.

Comment: sorry for misinterpreting... There is `doInBackgroud()` method. But there is also some code out of the method. Is that the reason why the progress dialog is disapearing soon?

Comment: @user3808179 Most likely.  The bulk of your work has to be done in that `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason using AsyncTask is suggested is because ProgressBar would otherwise be displayed using the UI thread which you do not want to do as it would block other operations the UI thread would have to do. You need to delegate the ProgressBar display to a background thread. So no, you can't do this.